# Reload some partial view in one page with parameter MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, parameter-passing, partial-views

I'm a student and also new in ASP.NET programming. I'm using Razor MVC view engine. I want to display some partial view in one page (Index.cshtml) using two datetime parameters (startDate & endDate) and with one button as trigger.
But I don't know how to pass the parameters to the Controller and then make the page reload with information between startDate & endDate.

`Index.cshtml` (Updated)

```html
@model LoginProject.Models.Date
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Welcome Maestro";
}
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS and bootstrap datepicker CSS used for styling the demo pages-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/themes/css/datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/themes/css/bootstrap.css">

    <div class="well">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <div id="result"></div>

                    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
                    {
                        <th>@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.start)</th>
                        <th>@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.end)</th>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Cek" class="btn btn-primary" id="sub" /></td>
                    }
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
    <!-- Load jQuery and bootstrap datepicker scripts -->
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script>
  
    $(function () {
        // disabling dates
        var nowTemp = new Date();
        var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

        var st = $('#start').datepicker({
            onRender: function (date) {
                return date.valueOf();
            }
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            if (ev.date.valueOf() > en.date.valueOf()) {
                var newDate = new Date(ev.date)
                newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
                en.setValue(newDate);
            }
            st.hide();

            $('#end')[0].focus();
        }).data('datepicker');


        var en = $('#end').datepicker({
            onRender: function (date) {
                return date.valueOf() <= st.date.valueOf()
                ;
            }
        }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
            en.hide();
        }).data('datepicker');
    });
</script>

    @{Html.RenderAction("baruLama", "Home");}
    @{Html.RenderAction("kunjunganPoli", "Home");}
```

`HomeController.cs`:

```html
using LoginProject.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace LoginProject.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private rsudwEntities5 db = new rsudwEntities5();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
   
            public ActionResult baruLama(Date date) 
        {
            if (date.start != null && date.end != null)
            {

                return PartialView("_totalKunjunganGender", db.getTotalKunjunganGender(date.start, date.end).ToList());

            }
            else
            {

                var today = DateTime.Today;
                var month = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
                var first = month.AddMonths(-1);
                var last = month.AddDays(-1);  

                return PartialView("_totalKunjunganGender", db.getTotalKunjunganGender(first, last).ToList());
            }

        }

            public ActionResult kunjunganPoli(Date date)
            {
                if (date.start != null && date.end != null)
                {

                    return PartialView("_totalKunjunganPoli", db.getKunjunganPoli(date.start, date.end).ToList());

                }
                else
                {

                    var today = DateTime.Today;
                    var month = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
                    var first = month.AddMonths(-1);
                    var last = month.AddDays(-1);

                    return PartialView("_totalKunjunganPoli", db.getKunjunganPoli(first, last).ToList());
                }

            }

    }
}
```

`Date.cs`:

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace LoginProject.Models
{
    public class Date
    {
        public DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("01/08/2014"); //set default to 1 august 2014
        public DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("01/09/2014"); //set default to 1 september 2014
        public DateTime m { 
            get { return start; } 
            set { start = value; }
        }
        public DateTime s { 
            get { return end; } 
            set { end = value; } 
        }
    }
}
```

To achieve that purpose what should I do?

Should I use Ajax?

Or Html.BeginForm?

But I can't use them to render multiple partial views.

Comment: use AjaxForm just google Ajax.BeginForm in asp.net mvc

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, Where I should put my @Html.RenderAction? The page is reload but take no effect. Sorry for asked too much.

Comment: show the updated code in your question

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad, Ok. Please take a look on Index.cshtml

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple ways you could do this, this is just one of them.

JQuery has a nice Load function you could use, each  time you call it, it will refresh the partial view. In this scenario, `BeginForm` is not necessary.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new  { id = "MyForm" }))
{

    @Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name("RefDate").Value("09/25/2014")            


    <input type="button" value="Load Data" id="MyBTN" />    
    <br/>   


    <div id="MyPartial">
    </div>                 
}


<script>

    $("#MyBTN").click(function () {

        var date = $("#RefDate").val();
        var int = 5;

        $("#MyPartial").load('Home/ViewPartial/?refDate=' + date + '&days=' + int);        
    });


</script>
```

`MyPartial` div will be the placeholder for your partial view that you will call. Your controller action would look something like this

```
    public PartialViewResult ViewPartial(DateTime refDate, int days)
    {                       
         MyModel model = new MyModel();
         //do stuff
         return PartialView("_MyPartial", model);
    }
```

The parameters values in the query string above must match the parameters that the controller expects.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confuse here, but still trying to implement it in my code. :D

Comment: Is my controller right? To receive the datetime parameter (start & end) from the view? I still can't reload it correctly =.

Comment: No, it looks like your controller is expecting a `Date` object. You are trying to call render action like this `@{Html.RenderAction("baruLama", "Home");}` and there is no data object being passed in that call

Comment: Yeah, so I should give Date object when I called the RenderAction? Is that right? Can you give me the right structure about the code please? Just one right example that can make my code works correctly.

Comment: Ya, but I change the Kendo part (I'm not using Telerik) with another datepicker thing. Not running well, more or less.